# Apache автоматически редиректит на localhost

Tags: apache2, redirect, httpd

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "C:\xamp\apache"
Listen 80
ServerName 10.28.16.200
```

При переходе по урл 10.28.16.200 автоматом редиректит на **localhost**. Как запретить в настройках этот редирект?

Comment: по-моему, это либо настройки браузера, либо *http-сервера* (включая содержимое файла `.htaccess` в корне сайта в случае, если в качестве *http-сервера* используется *apache*).

Answer (score -1):

1) В файле .../etc/hosts написано следующее

```
10.28.16.200 localhost
```

2)

```
<Files localhost/index.html>
    allow from all
    deny from 10.28.16.200
</Files>
```

Прошу не судить строго, не проверял т.к. нет Apache